# Disable textbox on radio button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two radio buttons.
each radio button has two TextBox
I just want to do if first radio button is clicked then other radio button containing textboxes should be disabled and vice versa.

Comment: please provide code, and/or jsfiddle.

Comment: actually right now I cant provide code because that code is at my office desktop. I have just stuck to this scenario at office.

Answer (score 5):

you can use jquery click event, combined with :checked filter

try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8NynQ/

```
<div>
    <label for="radio1">
         <input type="radio" name="test" value="radio1" /> Radio 1
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="for_radio1[]" class="radio1" disabled="true" />
    <input type="text" name="for_radio1[]" class="radio1" disabled="true" />
    <label for="radio2">
       <input type="radio" name="test" value="radio2" /> Radio 2
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="for_radio2[]" class="radio2" disabled="true" />
    <input type="text" name="for_radio2[]" class="radio2" disabled="true" />
</div>
```

and here is the js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input[type=radio][name=test]').click(function(){
    var related_class=$(this).val();
    $('.'+related_class).prop('disabled',false);

    $('input[type=radio][name=test]').not(':checked').each(function(){
        var other_class=$(this).val();
        $('.'+other_class).prop('disabled',true);
    });
});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Example:

HTML

```html
<form id="myform" name="myform" action="" method="post">
    <input type="radio" name="group1" value="Milk" checked="checked" />Milk
    <input type="text" name="text1" value="milk1" />
    <input type="text" name="text2" value="milk2" />
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" name="group1" value="Cheese" />Cheese
    <input type="text" name="text3" value="cheese1" disabled="disabled" />
    <input type="text" name="text4" value="cheese2" disabled="disabled" />
</form>
```

Javascript

```js
var form = document.forms['myform'];
form.group1[0].onfocus = function () {
    form.text1.disabled = form.text2.disabled = false;
    form.text3.disabled = form.text4.disabled = true;
}
form.group1[1].onfocus = function () {
    form.text1.disabled = form.text2.disabled = true;
    form.text3.disabled = form.text4.disabled = false;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K8FyR/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?

http://jsfiddle.net/UuwVG/

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" id="textbox1" onclick="check(this.id)" checked="true" />
<textarea id="textarea1"></textarea>
<br>
<input type="radio" id="textbox2" onclick="check(this.id)"/>
<textarea id="textarea2" disabled="true"></textarea>
```

Javascript:

```
function check(id) { 
var thistextbox = id.replace('box', 'area');
var othertextarea = 'textarea1';
if(id.slice(-1) == '1'){
    othertextarea = 'textarea2';
}
var othertextbox = othertextarea.replace('area', 'box');
document.getElementById(id).checked = true;
document.getElementById(thistextbox).disabled = false;
document.getElementById(othertextarea).disabled = true;
document.getElementById(othertextbox).checked = false;
```

}